# How to extend WordPress Bookly plugin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

> After several long hours of research, I've come to the conclusion that there are but two options:
>
> 1) Get the developers to create do the job (unfeasable);
>
> 2) Edit the plugin and change the name and source URL to prevent any updates from happening.
>
> Against all my convictions, I went with option #2. I will be closing this question but leaving this note as a reference for anyone who wishes to do something similar.

I need to extend the "Bookly" plugin and customize it with a few custom functionalities and edit some of the existing functionalities. I've never worked with OO PHP, not namespaces, but I have been reading a lot about it since starting this project.

As of right now, I (somehow) managed to edit some of the code to create new columns in the database and add data, however I cannot retrieve them.

1. I've logged every hook related to the plugin in order to trace where the loading occurs, all the way back to the `add_action` hook;
2. I've double-, triple-, and quadruple-checked every place through the original plugin and pinpointed which function I needed to edit;
3. I've created a new file calling the namespace and everything just like the original plugin (making sure I avoided duplicate class names and extended the original), but it's not being called. This is where I'm getting annoyed since I can get data to be added but not fetched using the same techniques.

When I worked on adding columns, it took a while, but it's now working no trouble. However, AJAX hooks are added dynamically, like so:

```
protected function registerWpAjaxActions( $with_nopriv = false )
    {
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
            $plugin_class = Lib\Base\Plugin::getPluginFor( $this );

            // Prefixes for auto generated add_action() $tag parameter.
            $prefix = sprintf( 'wp_ajax_%s', $plugin_class::getPrefix() );
            if ( $with_nopriv ) {
                $nopriv_prefix = sprintf( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_%s', $plugin_class::getPrefix() );
            }

            $_this = $this;

            foreach ( $this->reflection->getMethods( \ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC ) as $method ) {
                if ( preg_match( '/^execute(.*)/', $method->name, $match ) ) {
                    $action   = strtolower( preg_replace( '/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', $match[1] ) );
                    $function = function () use ( $_this, $match ) {
                        $_this->forward( $match[0], true, true );

                    add_action( $prefix . $action, $function );
                    if ( $with_nopriv ) {
                        add_action( $nopriv_prefix . $action, $function );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Before the `add_action( $prefix . $action, $function );` line, I've added a `wp_die( $prefix . $action );` if this was equal to `wp_ajax_bookly_get_customers`, which is the hook called when loading the data from the database. However, I cannot load the additional columns and their data despite because I cannot seem to extend the plugin before I can load the data from the database.

Comment: The Bookly plugin has an add on plugin called Custom Fields, does this not provide what you need?  https://codecanyon.net/item/bookly-custom-fields-addon/21113970

Comment: @AndrewSchultz the custom fields adds the fields to the front-end, whereas I need them in the back-end. My client wishes to use this as a CRM, therefore I need to be able to manipulate the back end client forms, as well as (eventually) adding a whole new module which is why I will need to be able to tap into the original plugin and customize it as I wish to.

Comment: I took a look at the plugin and there's no hooks or ability to override template files.  I'd look at another alternative rather than trying to make a circle out of a square.

Comment: Can you share you work so far? and what exactly are you trying to achieve? Because there are different way to do different thing and not the other way around.

Comment: @Ali_k I still need to find a way to both modify and existing module and add a custom module to the Bookly plugin.

Comment: Bookly is not a good plugin, because it never gives any option to edit or extend its functionality. If we have to extent it then go to bookly's developer which is not feasible. So there should be alternative of bookly and I am working to make alternate of bookly.

Comment: @shiv What a great initiative! I agree that it is not feasible, especially for very specific modifications. I really did not like working with it, and hopefully there will be something more developer-friendly. Keep us posted!

Comment: @davewoodhall I will try to complete bookly alternative plugin as soon as possible. May be take upto 2 months due to my busy schedule. But I will inform here. Thank you.

Comment: @shiv I as well have a busy schedule but if I may be of any assistance, please let me know, especially if we can fork and collectively remove Bookly !

Comment: @davewoodhall I have started work on it. spending daily 2 hours on it due my busy schedule. If I will need help I will inform. Thanks davewoodhall for your reply. May i have your contact number or email?

Comment: @shiv inbox me [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/davewoodhall13), I will gladly send my information over (just don't want to put it here for the world to see)